# How to compare an array of ScrollTops with Window Scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I many Boxes with different Margin-Top, I want to calculate the Margin-Top of all Boxes & then When a User scroll the window, if the window scroll is equal with one of the Boxes Margin-Top, Alert a something, I wrote the code below but doesn't work ...

```
$(function () {

    var TopPosition = [];

    $('.ScrollJS').each(function () {
        TopPosition = $(this).offset().top;
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var WindowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (TopPosition == WindowScroll) {
            alert('Hello !');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Thanks for your helping ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable TopPosition is Array.Using TopPosition.push  will you save all the $(".ScrollJs") elements margin–top value;
then you can each the TopPosition Array in Scroll method.

Comment: Thanks, My array now works and when I Alert it in Scroll function, It shows my value but It doesn't work when I scroll ..., How should I compare the values of an array with scrollTop ?

Comment: I think Array.prototype.each() method will work well in this situation